# load data into a FlatList - react native

Tags: react-native

**Good morning, I am bringing my data to a FlatList but it is not displayed, and the get route is working.**

//found
https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/vehiculos/vehiculos.php?id=40

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-microservice-80q49x?file=/src/App.js:0-1034

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [listaLibros, setListaLibros] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet = async () => {
   await axios
      .get(
        `https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/vehiculos/vehiculos.php?id=40`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setListaLibros(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet();
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{item.email}</Text>
          <Text>{item.tipo_usuario}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={listaLibros}
        renderItem={Item}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your API returns an object only, but FlatList data require an array. You may use `setListaLibros([response.data]);` in the axios request.

Comment: but how would it look in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your API returns

`{"id":"98","name":"","email":"WAN44D","n_email":"",...}`

It is an **object**, which does not satisfy FlatList data prop requirement. FlatList data require an **array**, so that the list can render components by loop.

You should modify your code and put an array in `listaLibros`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const [listaLibros, setListaLibros] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet = async () => {
   await axios
      .get(
        `https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/vehiculos/vehiculos.php?id=40`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        //edit this line
        setListaLibros([response.data]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet();
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{item.email}</Text>
          <Text>{item.tipo_usuario}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={listaLibros}
        renderItem={Item}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```